# Change pseudoclass before position with js or jQuery smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have in site left side `tab` with **onclick show or hide** smoothly.

Click the arrow and look  to show & hide this left side panel.

And you will see the **yellow image** [image] in left side of the `tab`

I  wondering is it possible to move bottom image   with the `tab`?

Like the `tab` move's smoothly this image must be move with this `tab`

I need to when slides hide it must be in `right side` when show it must be in `left`

```js
$(function(){
 $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {    
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.panel {
 width:300px;
 float:left;
 height:100px;
 background:#d9dada;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;

}
.panel:before {
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/jD3m2o/Summerbuble.png);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 44px;
    bottom: -44px;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.slider-arrow {
  height:90px;
 padding:5px;
 width:10px;
 float:left;
 background:#d9dada;
 font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
      </div>
      
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot select a pseudo-element using JS.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The image moves smoothly with the panel that slides out. What is it you want to do differently?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need to when slides hide it must be in right side when show it must be in left

Comment: So when do you want it to _move_ to the right then, and how? Currently, it stays on the left side, even when the panel is fully opened. So should it “jump” to the right side instantly first of all when hiding the panel starts, or …?

Comment: @CBroe if you will give me the right answer I'll accept it.I need to move it to left when is panel opened and otherwise move to right but smoothly .You can change anything in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly manipulate the `:before` pseudo-element, but you can manipulate the position of the `:before` element using class(es) on the `.panel`. For example (see `***` lines):

```js
$(function(){
 $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $(this).filter(".panel").addClass("showing"); // ***
          });
    $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {    
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $(this).filter(".panel").removeClass("showing"); // ***
          });
    $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.panel {
 width:300px;
 float:left;
 height:100px;
 background:#d9dada;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;

}
.panel:before {
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/jD3m2o/Summerbuble.png);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 44px;
    bottom: -44px;
    right: -44px;        /* *** */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.panel.showing:before {  /* *** */
    left: 0px;           /* *** */
    right: auto;         /* *** */
}                        /* *** */
.slider-arrow {
  height:90px;
 padding:5px;
 width:10px;
 float:left;
 background:#d9dada;
 font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
      </div>
      
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

I'm sure that's not *exactly* what you want to do (which remains a bit unclear to me), but that's how you can adjust the position of the yellow triangle.

Otherwise, you'll have to change it from being a pseudoelement to being a real element.

You might look at using CSS transitions instead, which let you move that pseudo-element much more smoothly:

```js
$(function(){
 $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
    $(".slider-arrow, .panel").toggleClass("show hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
 width:300px;
 float:left;
 height:100px;
 background:#d9dada;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;
}
.panel.show {
    transition: left 700ms;
}
.panel.hide {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left 700ms;
}

.panel::before {
    background: url(https://image.ibb.co/jD3m2o/Summerbuble.png);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 44px;
    bottom: -44px;
    right: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.panel.show::before {
    transition: right 700ms;
}
.panel.hide::before {
    /*transition: left 700ms;*/
    transition: right 700ms;
    /*left: auto;*/
    right: -44px;
}

.slider-arrow {
  height:90px;
 padding:5px;
 width:10px;
 float:left;
 background:#d9dada;
 font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;
  background:yellow;
}
.slider-arrow.show {
  transition: left 700ms;
}
.slider-arrow.hide {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 700ms;
}
.slider-arrow.show::after {
  content: '»';
}
.slider-arrow.hide::after {
  content: '«';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel show">
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show"></a>
```

Comment: __Otherwise, you'll have to change it from being a pseudoelement to being a real element.__ =( that is to bad .Ty for answer

Comment: @Spectr - Yeah, would be nice to be able to manipulate pseudoelements directly, but we can't. You can do a lot with the class thing, though. for instance, you can have a whole bunch of classes for intermediate states, and add/remove them during the transition. CSS transitions would probably be good too.

Comment: @Spectr - Added an example with CSS transitions.